# set session using connection request

Tags: java

i'm looking for way for setting session or cookie in external site using connection request.

I have site A which sends request to site B:

> 

```
          url = new URL(urlSCS + "test");
          connection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
          connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
          connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", 
               "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

          connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", "" + 
                   Integer.toString(urlParameters.getBytes().length));
          connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Language", "en-EN");  

          connection.setUseCaches (false);
          connection.setDoInput(true);
          connection.setDoOutput(true);

          //Send request
          DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream (
                      connection.getOutputStream ());
          wr.writeBytes (urlParameters);
          wr.flush ();
          wr.close ();

          //Get Response    
          InputStream is = connection.getInputStream();
          BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
          String line;
          StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer(); 
          while((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
            response.append(line);
            response.append('\r');
          }
          rd.close();

          responseSCS = response.toString();
          return responseSCS;

        } catch (Exception e) {

          e.printStackTrace();
          return null;

        } finally {

          if(connection != null) {
            connection.disconnect(); 
          }
        }
```

And on site B i want to create session or Cookie. Is it possible?

I understand that to set cookie or session the page should be displayed, beccouse cookie and session are written in browswer. But maybe there is some way ?

Comment: you can create cookie using `cookie` class in java and than send this cookie in your request. if thats what you need.Your question is a little unclear.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I get a cookie from an external webiste?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8820033/how-do-i-get-a-cookie-from-an-external-webiste)

Answer (score 3):

After the first connection you can get your session ID like this:

```
String mySession = connection.getHeaderField("JSESSIONID");
```

And in the next connections you can keep your session like this:

```
connection.setRequestProperty("Cookie", "JSESSIONID=" + mySession);
```

This way you can also retrieve/send any cookies as your java program were a browser or keep a session among different page requests...
More info:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/deployment/deployment-guide/cookie_support.html

See section "Programmatic Access to Cookies"

We use "JSESSIONID" assuming the site B is a java server site, change it for another name if it's a different kind of server