# How do I get a cookie from an external website?

Tags: java

I'm looking for help with something like this:

I have website A on which i set Cookie.

In this same browser o opened website B and i'm trying to connect from website B to website A using code:

> String responseSession = "";

```
     try {

     URL url = new URL(urlSCS + "session" );
     InputStream response = url.openStream();
     BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new
     InputStreamReader(response, "UTF-8"));


     for(String line; (line = reader.readLine()) != null;){
     responseSession += line;
     }

     }catch(Exception e){
     e.printStackTrace();
     }

     return responseSession;
```

to get the Cookie from website A.

The problem is that, when i open site A with Cookie the cookie displays correct, but when i'm trying to get the cookie by website B i get error:

> 

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet appServlet threw exception
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.esb.scs.SessionController.session(SessionController.java:81)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.invokeHandlerMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:176)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:436)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.handle(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:424)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:790)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:719)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:669)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:574)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter.doFilterInternal(OpenSessionInViewFilter.java:198)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:291)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:859)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:602)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
```

Comment: The other thing is - don't keep posting the same question over and over again.  This is three times now.  At least close your old questions.  You're making a mess.

Answer (score 3):

**Cookies cannot be shared across websites like this.**

When you set the cookie, it is a contract between your browser and website A.  When your browser connects to website B, it cannot access the cookie for website A because the cookie is on your browser.  You cannot transmit this cookie to website B so that it can use it on website A.  This is done for security reasons and cannot be worked around.

To transfer information from website A to website B, you should use a form POST operation from website A to website B and encode the data you need in the post.  Then website B can read this information from the POST operation instead of trying to get it from a cookie on website A.

Comment: I need to get Cookie becouse i want to create something like single sign-on module. I can't get session and i'm trying to autenticate user by using Cookies.

Comment: You have to pass the user authentication information in a POST operation from website A to website B and then authenticate.